# Using Selenium framework, how to check if chrome "right click menu" option is enabled or disabled?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

1. Go to cnn.com and wait until the page is finally loaded
2. Select URL address in the address bar and invoke context menu
3. Invoke context menu on any link within browser window

Expected Results

Step 3: 'Share link with e-mail' item is present and available in context menu

Step 4: 'Share link with e-mail' item is present and available in context menu

Comment: Under steps three and four of expected results, they're duplicated?  Is this correct, you might edit the expected results for a little more clarification.

Comment: I believe he's trying to determine if there's a context menu item of 'Share link with e-mail' when the user right clicks in menu bar or anywhere on page

Comment: You can open the context menu using Selenium but you can't see inside it because it's part of the browser and not the page.

Comment: Sorry guys, I just need to read context menu items and check if they are enabled or disabled, I'm testing browser based on chromium. And write tests on windows and on MacOs.  Do you know some tools to do this?